# Flip a div back to front with webkit transform CSS3

Tags: safari, webkit, css

I know it sounds a bit weird but can you flip a div back to front with -webkit-trasnform?

For example imagine a show window with writing on but you are looking at it from the inside so the writing is back to front.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to animate this effect? If not, you can just use rotateY to add a reflect effect.

-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);